# Product of two absolutely continuous measures

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose we have two probability measures on $\mathbb{R^{n}}$, $Q$ and $R$ absolutely continuous w.r.t $P$ and $\frac{dQ}{dP}$,$\frac{dR}{dP}$ is given. Is there a way to define multiplication for instance via Cauchy product such that we get a new absolutely continuous measure $S$ such that $\frac{dQ}{dP}\cdot \frac{dR}{dP}=\frac{dS}{dP}$ ?

Feel free so impose additonal conditions if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to define a multiplication of two measures absolutely continuous with respect to the same measure. By the Radon-Nikodim theorem, since $Q$ and $R$ are absolutely continuous with respect to $P$, there exists two $P$ measurable **functions** $q$ and $r$ such that
$$
Q(\mathrm{d}x) = q(x)\,P(\mathrm{d}x) \ \text{ and } \ R(\mathrm{d}x) = r(x)\,P(\mathrm{d}x)
$$
(i.e. $q(x) = \tfrac{\mathrm{d}Q}{\mathrm{d}P}$ and $r(x) = \tfrac{\mathrm{d}R}{\mathrm{d}P}$ in your notation).

One can then define the function $s(x) = q(x)\,r(x)$ (pointwise multiplication of functions, almost everywhere with respect to $P$) which is also $P$ measurable and then the measure $Q\cdot P$, defined for any set $A$ by
$$
(Q·R)(A) := S(A) := \int_A s(x)\, P(\mathrm{d}x)
$$
If $q\,r\in L^1(P)$, then $Q·R$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $P$.

Comment: ah! of course, well..the multiplication operator on $L^1$ by a $L^1$ function is not bounded but if one assumes that one of the Radon-Nikodym derivatives are bounded then that should be sufficient. E.g if $Q(A)\le P(A)$ for all $A$ for example.

Comment: Yes you are right, one should add the restriction that $q\,r$ is still in $L^1(P)$ to get that $Q· R ≪ P$